# Optimizing a Makefile

Tags: makefile

It's [been pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6512914/497934) (see the first comment) that my makefile rebuilds *all* source files regardless of changes made.

```
# Variables #

TARGETS := libAurora.a libAurora.so
    # The names of targets that can be built.
    # This is used in the list of valid targets when no target is specified, and when building all targets.

TARGET_DIRECTORY := ./Binaries
    # The place to put the finished binaries.

CXX := g++
    # The compiler to use to compile the source code into object files.

CXXFLAGS := -I. -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -g -O4
    # Options passed to the compiler when compiling source files into object files.

AR := ar
    # The archiver to use to consolidate the object files into one library.

ARFLAGS := -rcs
    # Options to be passed to the archiver.

SOURCE_FILES := $(shell find Source -type f -name *.cpp)
    # Because it's inconvenient to maintain an up-to-date list of all the source files
    # that should be compiled, we just search for all .cpp files in the project

OBJECT_FILES := $(SOURCE_FILES:.cpp=.o)

.PHONY: Default
    # The default target, which doesn't actually do anything except give the user instructions,
    # can be called even if nothing needs to be updated.

.INTERMEDIATE: %.o
    # Specifying the object files as intermediates deletes them automatically after the build process.

# Rules #

Default:
    @echo "Please specify a target, or use \"All\" to build all targets.  Valid targets:"
    @echo "$(TARGETS)"

All: $(TARGETS)

lib%.a: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(TARGET_DIRECTORY)/$@ $(OBJECT_FILES)

lib%.so: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(TARGET_DIRECTORY)/$@ $(OBJECT_FILES)
```

What can I do to improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the suggestion in the link you mention is to not bother with making your object files "intermediate".  I tend to agree.

If `make` deletes the object files after the link step then it has to re-build them all at the next invocation of `make`.  Without this, the next time you `make`, it can look at the dependencies of the object files (as specified by the makefile, the part after the `:`) and only rebuild them if the stated dependencies have a later timestamp.

You might also want a `make clean` target to remove the objects via `rm`, so that you can delete them when you really want to.  But the typical workflow for using `make` is to keep your object files around for extended periods and type `make` when you want to build what you've changed.